# React js reduce error : Type error: produts.reduce is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I do not what is causing the error TypeError: products.reduce is not a function

[image]

Code

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const Checkout = ({ products }) => {
    const getTotal = () => {
        return products.reduce((currentValue, nextValue) => {
            return currentValue + nextValue.quantity * nextValue.price;
        }, 0)
    };

    return<div>
        <div>Total: ${getTotal()}</div>
    </div>
}

export default Checkout;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: It's saying `products` is not an array. Check your runtime environment. Are you sure you're passing in the data that you expect? `console.log(products)` and see what the value is right before you hit your error

Comment: `products` can't get any data of array, make sure you receive data with `products`, you can check with `console.log(products)`, if everything is ok, then you need to check your internet connection or `API` logic with the postman or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this might be caused by `products` property not having a value.

This can simply be fixed by adding a default value of the property:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const Checkout = ({ products = [] }) => {
    const getTotal = () => {
        return products.reduce((currentValue, nextValue) => {
            return currentValue + nextValue.quantity * nextValue.price;
        }, 0)
    };

    return<div>
        <div>Total: ${getTotal()}</div>
    </div>
}

export default Checkout;
```

or:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const Checkout = ({ products }) => {
    const getTotal = () => {
        return (products || []).reduce((currentValue, nextValue) => {
            return currentValue + nextValue.quantity * nextValue.price;
        }, 0)
    };

    return<div>
        <div>Total: ${getTotal()}</div>
    </div>
}

export default Checkout;
```

Or return default value earlier:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const Checkout = ({ products }) => {
    const getTotal = () => {
        if (!Array.isArray(products)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return products.reduce((currentValue, nextValue) => {
            return currentValue + nextValue.quantity * nextValue.price;
        }, 0)
    };

    return<div>
        <div>Total: ${getTotal()}</div>
    </div>
}

export default Checkout;
```